# Какой код возвращает мышь при отжатии (Up)?

Tags: c#

Делаю прогу, которая будет отслеживать `MouseLeft Up` и `MouseLeft Down`

На данный момент, я имею такой код:

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);


        bool isLButtonDown()
        {
            Int16 state = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton);
            return (state & 0x8000) != 0;
        }
```

метод `isLButtonDown()` возвращает зажата ли левая кнопка мыши, код который она возвращает - `0x8000`. Меня как-раз и интересует, какой код возвращается при `MouseUp`

Надеюсь нормально объеснил:)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate#return-value

Comment: как вы это находите?) Я 30 минут искал

Comment: а как отслеживать, не совсем понял

Comment: честно говоря, только сейчас заметил, введя любой код, у меня фиксируется нажатие клавиши

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью дебага чекнул: 
`0` - **Up**
`-32768` - **down**

Comment: Ну так, согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate#return-value) _If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to `GetAsyncKeyState`._ То есть у вас код в вопросе написано верно, и с ним ничего не надо делать.